# spreadtab: column as text

Tags: spreadtab

In the following example I marked all entries in the first column as text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{spreadtab}

\begin{document}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{@{}cr@{}}}
@2017-04-30 & 120 \\ 
@2017-04-30 &  99 \\
@2017-04-30 & 150 \\ 
\end{spreadtab}
\end{document}
```

Is there a trick to mark the whole column as text without the @ sign? I mean some kind of preprocessing the raw data. Thanks in advance.